# Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379//: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused

Tags: django, redis, connection

`celery -A video_subtitle worker --loglevel=info`

```
-------------- celery@user-Inspiron-15-3520 v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.19.0-43-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2023-06-12 05:44:21
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         video_subtitle:0x7fbb41f5dde0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                `

[tasks]
  . `video.tasks.process_video`
  . `video_subtitle.celery.debug_task`

[2023-06-12 05:44:21,877: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to `redis://localhost:6379//: `Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)

[2023-06-12 05:44:23,883: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to `redis://localhost:6379//: `Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Trying again in 4.00 seconds... (2/100)

[2023-06-12 05:44:27,889: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to `redis://localhost:6379//: `Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Trying again in 6.00 seconds... (3/100)

[2023-06-12 05:44:33,898: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to `redis://localhost:6379//: `Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Trying again in 8.00 seconds... (4/100)

[2023-06-12 05:44:41,909: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to `redis://localhost:6379//: `Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Trying again in 10.00 seconds... (5/100)

[2023-06-12 05:44:51,924: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to `redis://localhost:6379//: `Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Trying again in 12.00 seconds... (6/100)
```

ChatGPT

Comment: did you start redis?

Comment: when I type redis-server in command prompt then ,
11742:C 12 Jun 2023 11:26:08.021 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
11742:C 12 Jun 2023 11:26:08.021 # Redis version=6.0.16, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=11742, just started
11742:C 12 Jun 2023 11:26:08.021 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
11742:M 12 Jun 2023 11:26:08.022 # Could not create server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use

Comment: so another process is already using port 6379

Comment: As @Razenstein tells, the redis-server is not yet started in the default port, either you need to use a different port while starting redis (and mention the port in celery)  or stop the application running on port 6379( only if the application running on 6379 is not required).